# Is there a way to create a new polymorphic foreign key relationship in Salesforce.com?

Tags: salesforce

Through consuming the [Salesforce.com Partner WSDL](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_partner.htm), I'm working on a synchronization between an external system and Salesforce.com. As you would probably expect, the objects that don't exist by default in Salesforce.com are being created as custom objects via the GUI. While I've had no problem porting over basic fields, I've had some problems with the relationships.

Some of the external system's relationships are defined by foreign keys which are polymorphic (as in, they can store the identifier for two or more different types). While I see that Salesforce.com [makes references in their documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm#soql_polymorph_keys) in how to deal with with polymorphic foreign keys in SOQL, I haven't found a way to actually create new polymorphic foreign key fields.

**Is there any way to create new polymorphic foreign key fields in Salesforce.com, or do you have to create individual foreign key fields for each type that could potentially be referenced?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to create your own polymorphic keys. The ones that come with salesforce are very specialized and have all sorts of custom functionality baked around them.

Comment: How did you confirm this? Have you found any official Salesforce.com documentation that explicitly mentions it?

Comment: I confirm as well. :) I don't think there is a single Apex developer in this world who has not tried, failed and fruitlessly desired to have a custom poly key ;)

Comment: I've not seen any documentation that says you can't; I've just never seen a way to do it. Here are some proposed ideas to add such a feature: http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqzBAAS https://sites.secure.force.com/success/ideaView?id=08730000000Bq7ZAAS

Comment: Maybe you can vote on the idea, though I wouldn't get my hopes up. http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqzBAAS

Comment: I'm marking this as correct. The fact that a strongly supported suggestion exists to add them is more than enough evidence for me. If anyone else stumbles on this question, upvote the links Jeremy and mmix posted!

Comment: Well, stands to reason they would have closed the idea were it possible to do it. Even though they rarely act upon development ideas I believe they do read them.